# Copying data from one pandas dataframe to other based on column value and separated by comma

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes viz., df1 and df2.

**df1** is like

```
Index YH   HE  MT  CU  EI
 0    Dot  Sf  Sy  Lc  
 1    Rls  Bd  Sa  Ta  
 2    Fs       Ft  Rg
```

And **df2** is like

```
Index   Z1   Z2  Z3
 0      YH       HE
 1      HE       EI
 2      MT       CU
```

I want a **df3** which looks like this

```
Index   Z1           Z2     Z3
 0      YH                  HE
 1      HE                  EI
 2      MT                  CU  
 3      Dot,Rls,Fs          Sf,Bd
 4      Sf,Bd              
 5      Sy,Sa,Ft            Lc,Ta,Rg
```

Basically, in one cell only but separated by a comma. The comma separated cell is obtained from df1.

In df3, the rows 3,4,5 correspond to rows 0,1,2

```
(0,Z1) of df2 is YH and column YH in df1 is Dot,Rls,Fs 
So Dot,Rls,Fs comes at (3,Z1) in df3

(1,Z1) of df2 is HE and HE column has Sf,BD in df1 
So Sf,Bd comes at (4,Z1) in df3
```

Similarly, for all others.

Please let me know if it is still not clear.

Comment: Please check the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer already contain in the previous question

```
s=df2.set_index('Index').astype(object).apply(lambda x : x.map(df1.set_index('Index').to_dict('l')))


pd.concat([df2.set_index('Index'),s.fillna('').applymap(','.join)])

Out[1798]: 
               Z1 Z2        Z3
Index                         
0              YH           HE
1              HE           EI
2              MT           CU
0      Dot,Rls,Fs       Sf,Bd,
1          Sf,Bd,           ,,
2        Sy,Sa,Ft     Lc,Ta,Rg
```

Update

```
s=df2.set_index('Index').astype(object).apply(lambda x : x.map(df1.set_index('Index').replace('',np.nan).stack().groupby(level=1).apply(list).to_dict()))
pd.concat([df2.set_index('Index'),s.fillna('').applymap(','.join)])
Out[1815]: 
               Z1 Z2        Z3
Index                         
0              YH           HE
1              HE           EI
2              MT           CU
0      Dot,Rls,Fs        Sf,Bd
1           Sf,Bd             
2        Sy,Sa,Ft     Lc,Ta,Rg
```

Comment: I am getting this   TypeError: ('sequence item 3: expected str instance, float found', 'occurred at index P1')

Comment: I just forgot to mention NAN  in the original question and apologies for asking similar question same.I felt that this is bit different and has weight-age of forming a different question altogether

Comment: @Rookie_123 No worry about it , it is hard for me find the different as well.

Comment: is there any way to remove those ,, appearing in Z3 column below Sf,Bd

Comment: The reason is that my actual dataset is big and just these commas in cells would create some problem

Comment: @Rookie_123 yw :-) have a nice day